# Does Algolia use ASCII or UTF-8 to calculate the size of an entry's JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, algolia

The Algolia [FAQ](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/basics/is-there-a-size-limit-for-my-index-records/#faq-section) says that the maximum size of an entry is a minified JSON size of 10KB. However it doesn't say whether the JSON string is ASCII or UTF-8 encoded so I'm not sure how to actually calculate that myself.

Edit: It also appears as if the Algolia UI doesn't enforce **any** size limit on entries.

Comment: 10KB is 10KB, independently of the encoding of the content.

Comment: I suppose if I'm only using the ASCII part of UTF-8 then that's true. I guess it's more appropriate to ask if Algolia supports UTF-8 up to 4 bytes in the entries

Comment: No, 10KB is still 10KB. Produce a properly encoded JSON file, minify it, measure how many KB it takes up. It doesn't matter what's in it as long as it's proper JSON. The only difference would be whether you encode non-ASCII characters as "\uXXXX" escape sequences or straight UTF-8 encoded characters, which will cause a difference of a few bytes. Either is valid JSON, but the question is whether Algolia prefers/expects/supports one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

As per deceze's comment, it's actually irrelevant because 10KB is 10KB. I can use either ASCII or UTF-8 and so long as the JSON file size is correct then that's all that matters.